# Make every element inside an iframe responsive

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design

I have an iframe which show ads. I want it to be responsive in such a way that every user with  different screen size can see it with 100% width instead of overflowing of the iframe. How to achieve this ?

Comment: The CSS for the iframe would ideally be responsive in nature but you might be able to adjust it with `.content()` using jQuery

Comment: Thanks @Deryck. Will you please explain more about .content() using jQuery ? I am confused.

Comment: Sorry I typo'd that - it's `.contents()` and you can adjust HTML content of a jQuery object using it.  Here is the best example for your use-case: http://api.jquery.com/contents/#example-1

Comment: So instead of `background-color` you would say `width` or `max-width` or whatever you're going for.  Just find the element ID / class to be precise with the alteration

Comment: That seems working but not for me as there are more than one elements in my iframe and it's difficult to track each element. I tried doing this   by setting the width:100px to iframe but then the effect took place only on iframe, where in my case i wanted something which can set width of every element inside iframe to 100%.
Anyway thanks for that idea @Deryck. :)

Comment: Once you get the contents back it's just like any other jQuery object - you can traverse and find groups of elements or use individual ones.  You can select all elements and do your 100% width using `$('#iframeID').contents().find('*').css('width', '100%');` .  Keep in mind the same-origin policy will apply here.

Comment: Your problem is probably stemming from this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Smashing Magazine has already tackled this problem using only CSS and a container element - [Embedded Responsive Design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/27/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/)

The Gist:

1. Create a container wrapper for the iframe in question
2. Style the container; 
   (if the container's class name was called 'video-container')

   .video-container {
     position:relative;
     padding-bottom: 56.25%;
     padding-top: 35px;
     height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
   }
3. Style the iframe inside the container

   .video-container iframe {
     position:absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }

Hope this helps!
Refer to the [link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/27/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
iframe, object, embed {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```